# Configuring Cassandra logback.xml

Tags: ubuntu, configuration, cassandra

I'm setting up Cassandra for the first time in Ubuntu (also using it for the first time). In logback.xml, I have the following:

`<file>${cassandra.logdir}/system.log</file>`

What is the `{cassandra.logdir}`, and where is it set? I thought it to be a environment variable, but doing echo on it returns nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is system property set in the bin/cassandra.

```
cassandra_parms="$cassandra_parms -Dcassandra.logdir=$CASSANDRA_HOME/logs"
```

With debian systems its overriden to be

```
cassandra_parms="$cassandra_parms -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra"
```